# How to find and store information with empty class and id?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

In python3 I want to extract information from a [site](https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/show.do?processo.codigo=01001DTQA0000&processo.foro=1&uuidCaptcha=sajcaptcha_380320b510ee415ca0ca56cfac794999) and put in variables

For example in the "Dados do processo" block I want to store:

```
"Indenização por Dano Moral"
"Direito de Imagem"
"Violeta Miera Arriba"
"R$ 38.160,00"
```

To isolate the block:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = 'https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/show.do?processo.codigo=01001DTQA0000&processo.foro=1&uuidCaptcha=sajcaptcha_380320b510ee415ca0ca56cfac794999'

try:
    res = requests.get(link, verify=False) # avoid SSLError
except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.RequestException, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout) as e:
    print(str(e))
except Exception as e:
    print("Exceção")

soup =  BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

janela1 = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"secaoFormBody"})[1]

dados_processo = janela1.find_all("tr",{"class":""})
```

For example, the information "Indenização por Dano Moral" is thus in dados_processo

```
<tr class="">
<td id="" valign="" width="150">
<label class="labelClass" for="" style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;;">Assunto:</label>
</td>
<td valign="">
<span class="" id="">Indenização por Dano Moral</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Please, does anyone know how to reach "span class="" id=“” ? I'm not getting it because it repeats itself in several points of the block in this way and with "" for class and "" for id

I thought about looking for the string "Assunto:" in "label class="labelClass" for="" " , if it is found, it takes the string in "span class="" id=“” 
This check can be useful because some similar sites may not have all the items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:contains` to target the *"headers"* and then [adjacent sibling (`+`) combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) for `td` containing the value of interest. This is using bs4 4.7.1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import urllib3; urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

r = requests.get('https://esaj.tjsp.jus.br/cpopg/show.do?processo.codigo=01001DTQA0000&processo.foro=1&uuidCaptcha=sajcaptcha_380320b510ee415ca0ca56cfac794999', verify=False)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('td:has(>.labelClass:contains("Assunto:")) + td').text.strip())
print(soup.select_one('td:has(>.labelClass:contains("Outros assuntos:")) + td').text.strip())
print(soup.select_one('td:has(>.labelClass:contains("Juiz:")) + td').text.strip())
print(soup.select_one('td:has(>.labelClass:contains("Valor da ação:")) + td').text.strip())
```

---

You could use `if` to test if present in case not:

```
soup.select_one('td:has(>.labelClass:contains("Assunto:")) + td').text.strip() if soup.select_one('td:has(>.labelClass:contains("Assunto:")) + td') is not None else 'N/A'
```